# Error message still showing up on successful user input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Ok with the help of stackers I was able to get an error message to show up below input form.

What I need is the error message to not be displayed when the user enters in any input in the form. What am I doing wrong?

Heres the HTML

```
<form id="url">
        <input type="text" name="urlName">
        <input type="submit" value="Build Your App"></input>
    </form>
    <div id="error-message">

    </div>
```

Heres the JS

```
document.getElementById("url").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            let errorMessage = document.getElementById("error-message").innerHTML = "Please provide your store URL";
            let myForm = document.getElementById("url");
            let formData = new FormData(myForm);
            if (formData.get("urlName") === "")
            return errorMessage;
            EndOfUrl = sanitizeDomainInput(formData.get("urlName"));
            newUrl = redirectLink(EndOfUrl);
            window.location.href = newUrl;
            return false;
        });


    function sanitizeDomainInput(input) {
        input = input || 'unknown.com'
        if (input.startsWith('http://')) {
            input = input.substr(7)
        }
        if (input.startsWith('https://')) {
            input = input.substr(8)
        }
            var regexp = new RegExp(/^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/)
            return regexp.test(input) ? input : 'unknown.com';

            
    }

    function redirectLink(domain) {
        return `https://dashboard.getorda.com/signup/?state=${domain}`;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are assigning the error message to the error message container div regardless of if there's an error which is causing the message to appear in ANY case.
- Refer below snippet where I've moved the error message assignment inside the error condition.

```js
document.getElementById("url").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  let errorMessage = "Please provide your store URL";
  let myForm = document.getElementById("url");
  let formData = new FormData(myForm);
  if (formData.get("urlName") === "") {
    document.getElementById("error-message").innerHTML = errorMessage;
  }
  EndOfUrl = sanitizeDomainInput(formData.get("urlName"));
  newUrl = redirectLink(EndOfUrl);
  window.location.href = newUrl;
  return false;
});


function sanitizeDomainInput(input) {
  input = input || 'unknown.com'
  if (input.startsWith('http://')) {
    input = input.substr(7)
  }
  if (input.startsWith('https://')) {
    input = input.substr(8)
  }
  var regexp = new RegExp(/^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/)
  return regexp.test(input) ? input : 'unknown.com';


}

function redirectLink(domain) {
  return `https://dashboard.getorda.com/signup/?state=${domain}`;
}
```

```html
<form id="url">
  <input type="text" name="urlName">
  <input type="submit" value="Build Your App"></input>
</form>
<div id="error-message">

</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank for you help!